# JS - Ciclo For , excluir un número en especifico del bucle

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas tardes, tengo este ciclo `For` que esta tomando una variable(`status`) de la base de datos con un `Json`, esta variable sirve para darle al ciclo `For` un limite para repetir el bucle pero quería saber como puedo tener un valor en especifico como por ejemplo `5` y que al hacer el bucle número `5` no lo imprima y siga con el bucle hasta su limite, se puede?

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.length != 0) {
        var status = data['Lockerstatus'];
        var tm = status.length;
        var men = 0;
        var evalua = "";
        for (var i = 1; i <= tm; i++) {
            evalua = status.substring(men, i);
            console.log(evalua);
            if (evalua == 0) {
                $('#lockercmb').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
            }
            men = men + 1;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('no encontramos nada');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que si se puede, lo que buscas es el comando `continue`.  Tu código quedaría así:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= tm; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
        continue;
    }
    evalua = status.substring(men, i);
    console.log(evalua);
    if (evalua == 0) {
        $('#lockercmb').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    }
    men = men + 1;
}
```

Comment: Lo voy a probar, muchas gracias por responder rápido :)

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias ;D